# Marginal independence and joint independence of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence

Could you help me to clarify whether this statement is correct:

Consider the random variables $A,B,C,D$ and let $\perp$ denote independence. Then, 
$$
(A,B)\perp(C,D) \rightarrow A\perp C
$$
My proof
$$
f_{A|C}=\int_{B}f_{A,B|C}dB\overbrace{=}^{(A,B)\perp(C,D) \rightarrow A,B\perp C}\int_{B}f_{A,B}dB=f_A
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um.. Yeah, it's like it.
But u use $(A,B)\perp(C,D)\rightarrow (A,B)\perp C$, u should prove it first.

Because $f_{A,B,C,D}=f_{A,B}f_{C,D}$
We have $f_C=\int f_{C,D}dD$, 
$$f_{A,B|C}=\frac{\int f_{A,B} f_{C,D}dD}{f_c}\\
=f_{A,B}$$
Then can complete the prove.

Comment: There are really some people who use *things* like $f_C=\int f_{C,D}dD$?

Comment: @Did No , i just imitate from STF..... will be convenient for him to understand...

Comment: ?? Another, more helpful, option would be to point that this is an incorrect notation and to correct it.